# Refresh a functional component from another one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh, react-functional-component

I have three files: App.js, A.js and B.js. A and B are functional components which are used in App.js. Within A.js I have a function foo(), and within this function I want to force B.js to re-render.

Any idea how to do this?

I googled this problem and found out that I could set a state in B.js and update that state. But how can I update this external state from foo() in A.js?

Comment: you need to use `shared state and functions`, pass a function and state to `A` and `B` from `App` and update the state using the passed down function in `A`, which would update the shared state and that would in turn re-render `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `state` in your `App`, then pass its `state` to `B` and `setState` function to `A` as `props`. Then whenever, you update the state through setState function from component `A`, it will cause to re-render the component `B`. It happens becuase react trigger re-rendering whenever props update.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to re-render it? If you pass props to a component it will automatically re-render if those props changes.

Comment: I have a function in my file A.js, and B.js should re-render DURING the function (inside of a loop). It doesn't work, only re-renders when the function is finished.

Comment: I need to see the actual code to help you any further. I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You can rerender a component by changing the key attribute value. every time the key is changed React unmount and mount the component.